# Implicitly pass arguments

Tags: c

I'm working on a custom unit-testing framework that doesn't display the filename/line numbers of failed tests. I know I could require them as arguments for the `report_results` function but that seems like a lot of text.

Is there a way to make it so that `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are always passed with the function, even if I don't pass them when I call it?

You can do something like this in C++:

```
void func(char *file=__FILE__, int line=__LINE__)(int more_args) {}
```

Comment: yes, with a macro

Comment: C doesn't support default parameters. Macros are the only way to do this

Comment: In C++ that doesn't do what you want; it will always display the line where the declaration is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a macro in your code, to call an underlying function

```
#define func(arg) real_func(__FILE__,__LINE__,arg)
```

where `real_func` is

```
void real_func(const char *file, int line, int arg);
```

In your code, when you call `func(12)`, it expands to a call to `real_func`, with actual file path and line of the call. You can even support variable argument functions in C99 with variadic macros as a frontend.

Comment: *You can even support variable argument functions in C99 with variadic macros as a frontend.* And if you're stuck with an ancient compiler, it's possible to support variable argument functions without C99's variadic macros if you have to - given the logging function `LOG( const char *fmt, ...)`, have the `LOG` macro expand to `log_step_one(__FILE__, __LINE__)` and have `log_step_one()` return a function pointer to `log_step_two( const char *fmt, ... )`.  `log_step_one()` saves the arguments, `log_step_two()` retrieves them.